# Changing innerHTML for SimpleModal and passing parameter to method raises error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a set of photos that I'm iterating through and showing on my index page. When I click on each picture, a modal is supposed to pop up and show a bigger version of the image. I am trying to use jQuery to change the innerHTML of the modal.

The problem is that when I try to pass the photo variable, I get an `undefined local variable or method 'photo'`. The index page does not load at all.

photos.js

```
jQuery(function () {
  $('.photo_container').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic_modal').html("<p><%= image_tag modal_url(photo), :class=>'modal_image' %></p>");
    return false;
  });

  $('.photo_container').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic_modal').modal({
      overlayClose:true
    });
  return false;
  });
});
```

The error occurs in the first function above where I try to pass some rails code for when .photo_container is clicked.

index.html.erb

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>


  <%= link_to '#', :class => 'basic' do %>
    <div class="photo_container">
      <%= image_tag flickr_url(photo) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div id="basic_modal">
  </div>

<% end %>
```

controller

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:search].empty?
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @title = params[:search]
      @photos = flickr.photos.search(:tags => params[:search], :has_geo => 1)
    end
  end
end
```

**Any clue on how I can pass my photo parameter?**

Comment: I don't see how `application.html.erb` fits into this. What am I missing?

Comment: @muistooshort That is where the jQuery script is loaded from. I placed it right before my closing body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the `image_tag` with the modal url in your erb. There's no need to add the content dynamically. You can hide the `basic_modal` div with some basic css. Then you can get rid of the first part of the javascript function.

Also that javascript code should be in `photos.js`, not in the application layout.

**Edit**

Here's how your erb should look like:

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>

  <%= link_to '#', :class => 'basic' do %>
    <div class="photo_container">
      <%= image_tag flickr_url(photo) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="basic_modal">
    <%= image_tag modal_url(photo), :class=>'modal_image' %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: When I do it that way, the modal would only display the first image regardless of which image I click. Also, thanks for the photo.js heads up.

Comment: We're also iterating through @photos so I ran into the problem of having multiple divs with id basic_modal (even though we hide it in the CSS)

Comment: @hyngyn That's weird. I added a sample code to see if we're on the same page.

Comment: The code you posted was what I initially had. The problem is that with each iteration, you're creating a basic_modal div. When I try to click on any image, it only loads up the bigger version of the FIRST image (not the correct image). This is why I have an empty basic_modal div so that I can alter the innerHTML with jQuery.

Comment: @hyngyn Actually you're iterating through each photo, so the url should be fine. Maybe the problem is in `modal_url`. What is that helper doing anyway? Also, try making "basic_modal" a class instead of an id

Comment: I figured it out. It was a scoping issue. If I move my script into the iteration, it works.